# How to make SSH in Google cloud keep running after closing the browser whilst running a .exe-file?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, server

I’m running a gameserver, more specifically a Terraria server on GCP. When I run ./TerrariaServer.bin.x86_64 (exe-file)
I have to input some settings for the server to run. Hence, nohup and & have not worked for me to keep the server running after I close the SSH-terminal. Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Do not use **hohup** for SSH sessions. The program will be terminated when the SSH session ends.

Instead use programs like [screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) or [tmux](https://www.hamvocke.com/blog/a-quick-and-easy-guide-to-tmux/).

[Techniques to Keep SSH Session Running After Disconnection](https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/)